# Google App Engine Cloud Storage Client won't Install

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to learn how to use Google Cloud Storage with Python.

My app is location is: myapp/lib

The documentation says to use:
"pip install GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient -t myapp/lib"

When I do I get:
"error: must supply either home or prefix/exec-prefix -- not both"

I have never used pip to install to a specific directory, I have just used it for my local Python installation.

I am under the impression that you need to be able to install 3rd party modules in the libs directory of your app in order for Google App Engine to use them. Is this correct?

How do people do this?

Leon

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to install BeautifulSoup. Finally I had just downloaded it manually and put it in a folder named 'bs4' inside of 'libs' and using it like this:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'libs')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

You should be able to download GCS from SVN as well, check out these links: 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/download
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/#Python_What_to_do_next

My app worked perfectly with BeautifulSoup in the 'libs' folder when deployed to google cloud appengine.

Answer (score 0):

You can cd to the app directory and just run "pip install GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient -t lib".

Alternatively, it can be downloaded directly from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient). You can then move the cloudstorage folder with your app.

Answer (score 0):

To install the client library on Windows 7 in my project, I used:

```
C:\Python27\scripts>pip install setuptools --no-use-wheel --upgrade
C:\Python27\scripts>pip install GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient -t <my_app_directory_root>
```

More [here](https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133).